# Non-contact thermometers used by China in screening for coronavirus (2019-nCoV)

Tags: thermal, optics, non-contact, thermal-camera, thermometer

I'm not sure if this is off-topic, but if it is, then please inform me, and I'll delete it.

In media reports of the spread of the "coronavirus" (2019-nCoV), we often see images of Chinese officials screening people using non-contact thermometers, similar to this:

> [image]

(https://www.sbs.com.au/news/china-admits-shortcomings-in-virus-response-as-cases-exceed-20-000)

I was wondering if anyone knew what the most common non-contact thermometers being used for this purpose are? I am aware of expensive thermal cameras and non-contact thermometers being used for disease screening, such as at airports and farms, with FLIR being the most common brand, but I think that it is very unlikely that the Chinese government is proving all of these officials with similarly expensive devices. So I am wondering what the most common types ("type" meaning brand, technical specifications, and cost) of non-contact thermometers are being used by these officials for the purpose of human fever screening/detection?

And related to the "types" of non-contact thermometers being used, there is an additional consideration. It might be assumed that these types of non-contact thermometers (whatever they are) are effective for this purpose (that is, effective for disease screening) -- after all, if they were not, then one would presume that they would not be used; but are they? If the Chinese are using lower-cost non-contact thermometers for this purpose, which, as I mentioned above, is likely a good assumption, then are these cheaper thermometers effective at detecting fevers in humans?

As I said, I realize that this might be off-topic, but, since it is a heavily technical question, and within the domain of electrical engineering, I cannot think of any other stackexchange website that would be more appropriate. My apologies if posting it here was a mistake; please inform me and I will delete it. Otherwise, I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to provide answers.

Comment: Non-contact thermometers are not that expensive, Amazon sells one for US$16. Measuring on the forehead is not the best place, somewhere more protected is better, such as the middle ear or armpit. However, these would more likely make contact.

Comment: @Mattman944 Yes, but there's a question as to the accuracy of a 16 USD non-contact thermometer.

Comment: I am more concerned about the method than the accuracy of the thermometer. As I suspected, my forehead is not a good indicator of body temperature. I have a "gun" type non-contact thermometer. My armpit measures 97 degF, my forehead measures 91 degF. Maybe if you calibrated by testing hundreds of people and healthy people usually measured 91 degF and people with a fever measured somewhat higher, then maybe this method would work, but I have doubts.

Comment: @Mattman944 Ahh, yes, you make a very good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://www.amazon.ca/Infrared-Thermometer-Non-contact-Temperature-Measurement/dp/B01HRSZQYM) consumer forehead one has 0.1°C resolution and they're essentially calibrating it with each "customer" so I would imagine it would be pretty good for finding outliers.

[image]

The forehead temperature is not going to match internal temperature or tympanic temperature but it might be good enough to find people with fevers. The particular product I linked claims +/-0.2°C accuracy.

It's designed specifically for measuring human skin temperature looking for fevers so it's not your Harbor Freight special for measuring a BBQ.

Hong Kong uses IR cameras for their post-SARS scanning, and I'm not sure they're any better. They're more efficient though, since they can scan people just walking by.

Among other things, the reading on an IR thermometer depends on the emissivity of the surface and the temperature of the sensor (the compensation may not be able to track fast slews). I would have guessed emissivity would vary quite a bit, but [this](https://www.thesnellgroup.com/storage/fck/File/thinkthermally/ThinkThermally_2007_Winter.pdf) source claims:

> In medical thermography we don’t encounter the same range of emissivity values because human skin is almost a perfect
>   emitter, or blackbody, with an emissivity
>   that is approximately 0.98

Which is a much better situation than trying to measure random items, which may be reflective or have other issues.

Because of the inherently poor match, I would think a tympanic type or a combo tympanic-forehead type would be best for home use (one could match the forehead reading the tympanic reading and get an idea whether it's worth shoving the tip into the kid's ear, which some kids don't like much), but that's just my opinion. Personally we used the tympanic IR type with ours. Note that it's still the same type of IR sensor, it's just got a  much better target to 'see'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "calibrating it with each customer"?

Comment: I mean that each normal person that goes by give the operator an idea of a 'normal' reading, so that when an outlier comes by it's obvious. That's assuming the feverish customers are rare and the customers are frequent enough that it doesn't drift much between customers.

Comment: Oh, I see. But doesn't skin color also affect the reading?

Comment: See the reference above. They say very little variation. There are scientific papers that have much more detailed analysis (eg. comparing black and white skin), and come to the same conclusion. Things can look little different in the IR spectrum compared to visible spectrum.

Comment: Interesting. Do you happen to have references to any of those scientific papers?

Comment: I scanned [this](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/journal-of-biomedical-optics/volume-14/issue-02/024006/Novel-approach-to-assess-the-emissivity-of-the-human-skin/10.1117/1.3086612.full?SSO=1) freely available one but I'm sure there are others.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I didn't read the paper you linked. But I suspect that a skin surface, if dry and not hairy and relatively flat over the "acceptance spot size," is probably a diffuse and lambertian. If the measuring wavelengths are where skin is essentially a black absorber, then the emissivity of 1 is acceptable. I'd expect a couple of guide lights (lasers?) that form a single spot when the right distance is achieved (important) because there is also light coming in from the surrounding environment and calibrating that out would require ambient temp and knowledge of that "leakage."

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the information, Spehro. @jonk, can you please elaborate on what you just said? I found it quite interesting. Any chance you also have some research papers on what you just mentioned?

Comment: @ThePointer What would you like "elaborated?" I said a variety of things. One is that I was thinking "specular vs matte" when talking about "diffuse." Another is that I was talking about the usual "Lambertian" distribution (simple cosine law.) Another is that I was considering the acceptance angle of the sensor + baffles + optics (where they exist, anyway.) Another is the surface itself and the proportions of transmissive, absorptive, reflective (which must add to 1.) And the admission of external surrounding sources into the acceptance. Anything more specific than "elaborate?"

Comment: @jonk Pretty much everything you said in relation to skin and getting accurate thermal measurements; they all seem like vital considerations. I'm assuming there are papers that look into this?

Comment: @ThePointer But I'm no expert on long IR pyrometry (or skin) or devices for same. (It's a terrible environment as everything is emitting with nearby distributions.) My decades of work is in near-IR and V-band pyrometry, which has different problems, starting in the late 1980's working with Dr. Ray Dills (after he left NIST.) I also work in phosphor thermometry. I'm sure there are papers on these cheap systems. Here, I was merely thinking off-the-cuff from my experiences and extrapolating/projecting. Nothing more.

Comment: Nor do I pretend to be an expert. I've run across some of the factors from time to time. There's at least one fellow who frequents here who probably knows a lot more, having worked for one of the IR instrument companies, maybe he'll put in his two cents.

Comment: @jonk Oh, ok. Well, thank you both for the information, nonetheless.